# Finding start and end character alone

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is 2 words:

Good : `abc_-abc`

Bad : `_abc_` or `-abc-`

Meaning it can be allowed the `-` or `_` in between but not in start and end.
How to test using regexp?

any one help me?

my try: `/\w(?![^_|^-])/g` - But not works.

Comment: Could you clarify: are you extracting words or validating a full string? If extracting try `/\b[^\W_]+(?:[\w-]*[^\W_]+)?\b/g`

Comment: If you validate, try `/^[^\W_]+(?:[\w-]*[^\W_]+)?$/`

Comment: We'd be glad if you clarify the problem you have. Otherwise, the solutions might be quite far from what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following regex to ignore `_` and `-` form starting and ending of the string.

```
^[^-_](.*[^-_])?$
```

```js
function test(s) {
    return /^[^-_](.*[^-_])?$/.test(s) ? 'Good' : 'Bad';
}

console.log(['abc_-abc', 'a', 'abc or -abc-'].map(test));
```

**Regex Explanation graph:**

[image]

Regex [**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/4GvuEL/1/).

Comment: This won't match 1 letter strings, and definitely won't match just *words*. `i` is redundant here as the pattern does not contain any case-ful chars.

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew, I noticed and updated the regex.

Answer (score 0):

You could check for the first and last character if it is not an unwanted character.

```js
function test(s) {
    return /^[^-_](.*[^-_])?$/.test(s);
}

console.log(['abc_-abc', 'a', 'ab', 'a-b', 'abc or -abc-', '-', '-a', 'a-'].map(test));
```

Comment: Your `^[^-_](.*[^-_])*$` pattern is [fraught with](https://regex101.com/r/TVz4QS/2) catastrophic backtracking

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, now it should work with zero or one quantifier.

Comment: Actually, `^[^-_](.*[^-_])?$` will not cause CA, but it is unlikely to work for OP since `[^-_]` matches any char but `-` and `_`, not just letters (OP says they want to match "*words*")

Comment: i miss some more use cases, and *words* are just a description, without meaning, as far as i read the question.

Comment: `^[^-_](.*[^-_])?$` matches a blank line, is 50 spaces a "word"?

Answer (score -1):

below answer works fine:

[a-z]{0,90}[_][-][a-z]{0,90}

Comment: I suggest you test your regex at http://regex101.com. You will see your patterns do not do what is required at all. Please at least explain why you think these patterns are relevant for the current scenario.

Comment: [a-z]{0,90}[_][-][a-z]{0,90}

Comment: Ashish, if the above pattern is tested and answers OP's question then please edit your answer and place the correct pattern.